# How do I find the APP_UUID in Xcode for an iOS App?

Tags: ios, xcode, uuid

iOS Simulator stores apps in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/APP_UUID/

But how do I find the APP_UUID for a specific Project/Target?

Answer (score 7):

Go to

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
```

and type

```
find . -iname "*.app"
```

in a shell.

** Updated for Xcode 8 **

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data for the paths of more recent versions of the simulator

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is to run the app in the simulator and NSLog the result of a standard path-locating function, like this one:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                         YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}

// elsewhere, like in -application:didFinishLaunching:withOptions:
NSLog(@"app doc directory: %@", [self applicationDocumentsDirectory]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
xcrun simctl get_app_container booted com.bundle.identifier
```

just change `com.bundle.identifier` to your app bundle identifier

- https://medium.com/@ankitkumargupta/ios-simulator-command-line-tricks-ee58054d30f4
- https://nshipster.com/simctl/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to remember these commands, a very simple and straightforward way is to simply:

1. open `top` (or any activity manager)
2. search for your application name

The location where your app is stored will be there