# Finding the path of the iOS Simulator app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I want to run the **simulator** from the command line. Is there any way to find the **simulator path** through **command line**. Apple frequently changes the simulator location like

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator

/Applications ........ / IOS simulato....
```

Is there any way to find the simulator path from terminal. ?

Comment: Use "NSTemporaryDirectory ()".  Look this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data/32087374#32087374

Comment: @Shubhendu the OP question was "from the terminal", not "from code" ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two suggestions:

- You can use `xcode-select` to print the path to Xcode:

  ```
  # This returns sthg like "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
  XCODEPATH=$(xcode-select --print-path)
  # Then build the rest of the path to the simulator SDK
  SIMSDKPATH=${XCODEPATH}/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
  # And add the rest of the path to the Simulator app
  SIMULATORPATH=$(SIMSDK}/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator
  ```
- You can use `xcrun` to find the path of a xcodebuild tool in the iphonesimulator SDK, then deducting the path from here:

  ```
  # This returns sthg like "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc"
  GCCPATH=$(xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator -find gcc)
  # Then go up 3 directories
  SIMSDKPATH=$(dirname $(dirname $(dirname ${GCCPATH})))
  # And down to the Simulator app
  SIMULATORPATH=${SIMSDKPATH}/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator
  ```

Comment: Use "NSTemporaryDirectory ()".  Look this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data/32087374#32087374