# How to copy sqlite database when application is launched in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I want to copy my sqlite database from the database location with latest updates to my iOS application every time I launch the application.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Kindly, make sure for such questions, you do list references to What Have You Tried sources or simply write in your code here so that everyone can know yur method/approach

Answer (score 17):

you can add following methods to your appdelegate

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) {

       NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
       success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

       if (!success)
          NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath
{   
    //Search for standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    //First Param = Searching the documents directory
    //Second Param = Searching the Users directory and not the System
    //Expand any tildes and identify home directories.

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"dbpath : %@",documentsDir);
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
}
```

and call this method in your did finish with launching method
**`[self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];`** hope this will help.

Comment: no, if your original database is dirty, you want to keep the user activity data instead of overwriting the whole database.

Comment: Is newly replaced database writable? I have replaced a database but it became readonly. How can i make it writable?

Comment: for anyone else coming here and needing the data of the tables You need to copy the ``.sqlite-wal`` and ``.sqlite-shm`` files as well.

Answer (score 4):

use below code for coping database when application launch

in your appdelegate.m

in

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

  [self getdatabase];

  return YES;
}
```

and add below function in to your appdelegate.m

```
-(void)getdatabase
{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *DBPath = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = @"";
    writableDBPath = [DBPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"writableDBPath:%@",writableDBPath);
    success = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz.sqlite"];
       success = [filemanager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBpath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
       if (!success) {
            NSAssert(0, @"failed to copy database at path with message '%@'.",[error localizedDescription]); 
        }
    }     
    NSLog(@"111writableDBPath:%@",writableDBPath);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in Swift 4/5

```
    func copyDatabaseIfNeeded(sourcePath : String) -> Bool {
      var destPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
      destPath = destPath + "/foo.db3"
      let databaseExistsWhereNeeded = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destPath)
      if (!databaseExistsWhereNeeded) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: sourcePath, toPath: destPath)
            print("db copied")
        }
        catch {
            print("error during file copy: \(error)")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: My similar code is compiling fine in Xcode 11.4 - so, yes - if you are having trouble, let me know.

Comment: Great thanks. It seems to be working fine. I just wondered if Swift 5 allowed it to be optmized to fewer lines or anything. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
NSArray *docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *strDocDirectory = [docPath objectAtIndex:0];

    self.strDatabasePath = [strDocDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:YOUR_DB];


    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: self.strDatabasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [self.strDatabasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3 *contactDB;


        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YOUR_Table (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }

            sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **AppDelegate Class**

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *dbPath;
```

.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
}
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    dbPath = [self getDBPath];

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success)
    {
       NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampleDB.sqlite3"];
       success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
       if (!success)
          NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

/********* Database Path *********/
- (NSString *) getDBPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampleDB.sqlite3"];
}
```

It'll automatically copy, if it doesn't found any database in application.

Hopefully, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this, it'll definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)openDatase{  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    self.databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"weightCal.sqlite"];  
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {  
        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened ");  
    } else {   
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database ");  
    }  
}

-(void)dealloc{
    sqlite3_close(database);
    [super dealloc];
}


-(void)copyDatabase {
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath];
    if(success) {
       return;
    }
    NSString *defaultPath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];
    success=[fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writablePath error:&error];
    if(!success){
       NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@' .",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Declare following teo variable in `.h`:

```
sqlite3 *database; 
NSString *databasePath;
```