# error in sqlite3 table creation 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, xcode5.0.1

I'm having a problem in creating table with sqlite3 , I created the database in the code but it gives an error :  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not create table'

I tried to review the code to find bugs but I couldn't find any.
here is some of the code.

```
-(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"dbfile.sql"];
}


-(void)openDB
{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0,@"Database Failed to Open");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Database Opened !");
    }
}

-(void)createTable:(NSString *)tableName
        withField1:(NSString *)field1
        withField2:(NSString *)field2
        withField3:(NSString *)field3
        withField4:(NSString *)field4
{
    char *err;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST '%@' ('%@'TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' INTEGER, '%@' TEXT);",tableName,field1,field2,field3,field4];
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0,@"Could not create table");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Table Created");
    }
}
```

and I import `sqlite3.h` but every time I run the simulator it crashes and gave me that error.

please help me,Thank you.

Comment: Try to reimport your database file

Comment: I'm creating the database in the code

Comment: No. You're not. You're not creating the database from the code shown above. If you haven't included the database creation code, please make sure that your database exists at the path..

Comment: And after the execution of code you can check whether DB is created or not.

Answer (score 0):

copy db again in your xcode and check below link for copy database to iOS :

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491238/how-to-copy-sqlite-database-when-application-is-launched-in-ios)

and than try to create tabels

Answer (score -1):

```
-(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/dbfile.sql"];
}
```

the path is not right

Comment: You are copy-pasting OPs code as answer. To comment on something in the code, consider posting a comment instead.