# why the data is not inserting in database sqlite but show data that i take static path and inserted?

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert

////this method use for show data and that works

```
    NSString *databasePath =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images.db"];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK){

        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM IMAGEDATA";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
           NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
    else{

          while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

               NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 1) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 1)];

               imagesfromdb =[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
               NSLog(@"IMAGE :::%@",imagesfromdb);
              [databaseimage addObject:imagesfromdb];

             //imageData is saved favicon from website.

       }
    }
  }
```

/////this method use for insert data.

```
   const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

  if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database)==SQLITE_OK)
  {

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1);   
    const char* sqliteQuery = "INSERT INTO IMAGEDATA (NAME, IMAGE) VALUES (?, ?)";
   //sqlite3_stmt* statement;

   if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqliteQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
   {
       sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [fileName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
       sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imageData bytes], (int)[imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
       sqlite3_step(statement);
   }
  else NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );

   // Finalize and close database.
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);

   }
```

this method not working i cant understand but this method show data until i close the app. but after that the data will be gone and didnt save in db file

Comment: You must check the return value of all functions, especially `sqlite3_step()`.

Comment: how can i check that and how i can know that the data is inserted

Comment: You check it like for any other function (and I suggest reading [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the assets inside `mainBundle` of your app sandbox have `readonly` property. That's why in your case you are able to read the data but not modify it. So you should first copy your database file to `DocumentDirectory` which has `readwrite` access, and then you will be able to perform the `write` operation in that db. Check this question to understand how to copy database file from mainBundle to `DocumentDirectory`.

[How to copy sqlite database when application is launched in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491238/how-to-copy-sqlite-database-when-application-is-launched-in-ios)

You can follow this [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm) as well to understand all steps