# Where Does Simulator 8.0 Store Files

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

I cannot find the directory for the new simulator data in Xcode-6 Beta for IOS 8

It is not in
~/Library/Application Support/IPhone Simulator/

[Where does the iPhone Simulator store its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data)

Comment: you might wanna be careful about iOS 8 and Xcode 6 questions...it's still under NDA

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I don't understand why there are TAGs for these though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290989/xcode-6-iphone-simulator-application-support-location

Comment: Try this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133022/ios-8-store-sqlite-file-location-core-data/27461267#27461267

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like this:

```
/Users/{YOUR NAME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APPLICATION ID}/
```

The Device ID can be a bit hard to find (basically, there's one folder with a random-looking name for each simulator you have). To get to the correct folder, I used this terminal command:

```
find ~ -name myFile.txt
```

Where `myFile.txt` was one of the files in my application. The terminal then printed out the full location—this might be more useful to you then checking each one-by-one, if you have a file (or, can make one) that you can search for.

Comment: IIRC, on apple.stackexchange.com they don't allow such questions (on products under NDA)

Comment: If your app uses CoreData, a nifty trick is to search for the name of the sqlite file.  find ~ -name my_app_db_name.sqlite

Comment: How will you know the APPLICATION ID?

Comment: You can find Device ID in the list of devices in xCode. You can either go xCode->Window->Devices or Press ⇧⌘2 (Shift+Command+2) buttons. Then choose simulator you need, select it and see the Identifier under Device Information

Answer (score 12):

In XCode 6 it's really hard to find out. But I do this in the simple way:

With XCode opened just write this in Debug Area:

#### po [NSBundle mainBundle]

Or logging:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSBundle mainBundle]);
```

The result is something like that:
[image]

After that you can open Terminal app and go to path with this command:

#### open yourAppPath...

---

[Update]

I found an amazing app to do this: http://simpholders.com/

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: **Swift 3 -** po Bundle.main

Answer (score 2):

To locate the *Documents* folder of an app in iOS 8 Simulator, you can first write a file in the Documents folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Words.txt"];
NSString *content = @"Apple";
[content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

say, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Then you can open a Terminal and find the folder:

```
$ find ~/Library -name Words.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was frustrated trying to find things manually. Ill keep my notes above to show what does NOT seem to work.

What DOES work, and is a great relief to me, is SimPHolders.    Google it.  Download it.  Run it.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Simulators directory in XCode6 is moved to:

```
Library ▸ Developer ▸ CoreSimulator
```

Full Path to Application folder:

```
~/ ▸ Library ▸ Developer ▸ CoreSimulator ▸ Devices ▸ 5D71993D-78C2-49F4-9B30-99D0307D3A2F ▸ data ▸ Containers ▸ Data ▸ Application ▸ AE50273B-993C-45DA-97E8-3F88E4B64BDE ▸ Documents ▸ xyz.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

With the simulator open, go to Hardware->Devices->Manage Devices.

A Window shows, outlining each of the simulators available, and the Unique Identifier that goes with each one.

Therefore, after you have navigated in Finder to ~Library/Developer/CoreSimulator as others describe above, you can tell which of the directories therein contains the simulator you want, by looking for the Unique Identifier.

Once inside there, you still need to drill down further... in my case I found I had to navigate into data/Containers/Data/Application, then look for the folder inside that had todays date.

Finally!  I arrived at my familiar Documents and Library folders.

Thanks Apple once again, for keeping us iOS developers gainfully employed!

Comment: HOWEVER!  Still a mystery.  Because after I deleted the contents of that data directory (such as Library/Caches), I run my app in the simulator again, and the contents never re-populate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add NSLogs in application delegate "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method, so they print your paths

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSLog(@"APP BUNDLE :: %@", [NSBundle mainBundle]);
    NSLog(@"APP DOCUMENTS :: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
#endif
...
```