# Issue with creating database in iOS using phone gap

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova

I want to use sqlite db for my iOS application using phone gap. I add sqlite plugins,         linked sqlite libraries. Did everything correct, when I run my app in emulator iOS 6.1, it  launches fine but not giving any alert, I want to display on db success  etc. Also I don't know if database is created successfully, where can I find that db file. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Storage Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lawnchair.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/Lawnchair-sqlitePlugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for Cordova to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // Cordova is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {

                 alert("correct");
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }

        // Populate the database
        //
        function populateDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
        }

        // Transaction error callback
        //
        function errorCB(tx, err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
        }

        // Transaction success callback
        //
        function successCB() {
            alert("success!");
        }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>Database</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cordova.js` file is normally in the `<project_name>\platforms\android\assets\www` directory.
You have shown it to be in `<project_name>\platforms\android\assets\www\js` as per your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

You need to check the correct path of your `cordova.js` file. If it is in `www` directory than you need to change the `script` tag as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Is the `onDeviceReady()` function being fired? 
is the `alert("correct")` being called?

Comment: cordova.js is in js folder inside www directly. I think onDeviceReady() function not being called neither throwing any alert.

Comment: can you try to **comment** out `lawnchair.js, SQLiteplugin.js and lawnchair-sqliteplugin.js` and check whether it works?. The cordova app will use built-in WebSQL as the sqlite db.

Comment: now i imported the latest cordova.js for iOS, it gives the success alert. Now my question is where i can find my db file, which is created now

Comment: have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data) for app data storage location.

Comment: it does not give a clear way to find the directory where database is created