# iOS Simulator data Sharing

Tags: ios, macos

I've a java object which is created on Mac, on the same machine I am running iOS Simulator with my application, is there anyway i can share my data object between Mac application and iOS application running on Simulator?

Any pointer will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick thoughts:

2 different languages sharing a piece of data ? XML sounds like a good plan. If it is heavy handed, may be JSON could work for you.

I am aware you mentioned both apps are working on the same machine (at the moment) but what happens if you move mobile app to a device? What happens if your mobile app:

1. opens a socket
2. reads XML for the data object from it
3. closes the socket
4. does its magic with the object?

Would it work for you ?

**UPDATE**

Check this out please: [Where does the iPhone Simulator store its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data)

However keep in mind that, as far as I know, this location may change from version to version.

It does not matter if you read it from a file or a socket, don't you have to change the mobile code? And sockets and files are just streams in *nix lingo, aren't they ? :]

Comment: Thanks Alp for quick response. No we are not going to move it to actual phone. This is our test env where we are running thousands of cases and having difficulty in sharing the data between mac and simulator env. The approach you suggested requires changes in application running on Sim so that i can read from a particular socket. However is it possible to share the data through the mac file system? Since Sim also write to same file system.