# Which app does app ID in /Application folder belong to?

Tags: ios, xcode, simctl

I was able to get bundle identifiers for all apps installed on iOS simulator by going to directory

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/
```

but how do I know which app the ID belongs to? Are there names? Why are all IDs numerical? Are they randomly generated and different on each sim?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it is random number. Why apple use this kind of mechanism, But you can get application bundle identifier by using below step.

Step:1

**Goto:** `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/`

Step:2

Select Any application > Open `.com.apple.mobile_container_manager.metadata.plist` file.

Step:3
Value for `MCMMetadataIdentifier` is identifier for your application you can also see in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: just parse hidden file for bundle id ...

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/< device id >/data/Containers/Data/Application/< app id >/.com.apple.mobile_container_manager.metadata.plist

Answer (score 0):

> Why are all IDs numerical? Are they randomly generated and different on each sim?

I believe they’re different on every device, and that the idea is to make it more difficult for malware to figure out whether and where a given app is on the device.